# pointer to char array C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I have problem converting next code from c to c++:
I have a function that takes an array of move sequences (sequence of chars from a to i) as arg.

code:

```
void mkmove(char** move) {
    int i = 0;
    char* p = NULL;
    int moves[9][9];

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(p = move[i]; *p; p++) {
            moves[i][*p - 'a'] = 3;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char* movestr[] = {"abde", "abc", "bcef", "adg", "bdefh", "cfi", "degh", "ghi", "efhi"};
    mkmove(movestr);

    return(0);
}
```

gcc compiles that code fine, but if I try to compile it with g++ it gives me next warning:
main.cpp:17:39: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]

I believe this warning comes from the fact that string in C is defined as char[], while c++ uses std::string.
So I tried replacing the code to use C++ strings like this:

```
void mkmove(std::string* move) {
```

in mkmove function defenition, and:

```
std::string* movestr = {'abde', "abc", "bcef", "adg", "bdefh", "cfi", "degh", "ghi", "efhi"};
```

in main function and add the C++ string header file:

```
#include <string>
```

but now I get errors:
main.cpp: In function ‘void mkmove(std::string*)’:
main.cpp:11:21: error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘char*’ in assignment
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:19:39: error: scalar object ‘movestr’ requires one element in initializer

I also tried some other tweaks but that gave me least errors on compile.

So what is proper way to convert top code from C to C++?

Thanks for answers!

-Slovenia1337

Answer (score 5):

use

```
std::string movestr[] = {"abde", "abc", "bcef", "adg", "bdefh", "cfi", "degh", "ghi", "efhi"};
```

Comment: Or (using C++11) `std::vector<std::string> movestr = {"abde", "abc", ... };`

Answer (score 5):

No, the warning isn't because you should use `string`, it's because character strings are read-only.

Either declare strings as `char ...[]` or as `const char *`.

In your case, you're declaring an array of `char *`, which is a deprecated feature (converting from `const char *` to `char *`.

Comment: +1 for explaining what the error really means, but it's probably best to switch from `char*` to `std::string` instead of `char const *`

Comment: Absolutely. But if he's converting C code to C++, it'll be orders of magnitude harder to switch everything over to `string`, this'll just make his life that much easier.

Comment: I guess which way is best depends on how much has to be converted. If the above code is actually the whole program I'd switch over to C++ types. (Of course its obviously not a whole program, or if it is it doesn't do anything)

Answer (score 0):

> I believe this warning comes from the fact that string in C is defined as `char[]`, while c++ uses `std::string`.

No, in C string literals are constant `char[]`, while in C++ they are to `const char[]`.

Fix the const-correctness of your program thus:

```
void mkmove(const char** move) {
    const char* p;
    int moves[9][9];

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(p = move[i]; *p; p++) {
            moves[i][*p - 'a'] = 3;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    const char* movestr[] = {"abde", "abc", "bcef", "adg", "bdefh", "cfi", "degh", "ghi", "efhi"};
    mkmove(movestr);

    return(0);
}
```